# Arelle Webserver - How to extract the actual label text [not the Standard tag text ] from XBRL filing?

Tags: xbrl, arelle

I use Arelle Webserver different [views](http://arelle.org/documentation/api-web-services/) to extract tags from XBRL filing. However it looks like they do not extract the actual lable text. Is there a way to extract the actual label text [not the Standard tag text] from XBRL filing?